# Not able to hit the controller in Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I created a Empty WebAPI project and added an empty controller with this code:
Added a OrderStatus class in the models folder with two props Id & Status. Nothing fancy.

```
public class OrderController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public OrderStatus GetOrderStatus(long orderStatus)
    {
        OrderStatus order = new OrderStatus() { OrderId = 10, Status = "2" };

        return order;
    }
}
```

Here's the code in WebApiConfig:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

When I hit 
    port/api/Order/OrderStatus
Port meaning localhost, the browser give this error:

```
<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI '/api/Order/OrderStatus'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No action was found on the controller 'Order' that matches the request.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

What am I missing?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to name your parameter "id"

But I would prefer to use the attribute routing. In my opinion they are more intuitive.

```
public class OrderController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet, Route("api/order/{orderStatus:long}")]
    public OrderStatus GetOrderStatus(long orderStatus)
    {
        OrderStatus order = new OrderStatus() { OrderId = 10, Status = "2" };

        return order;
    }
}
```

Be aware that you have to write the parameters in curly brackets. And if the parameter is not of type `string` then you have to add the type like in my example.

Answer (score 0):

If you use WebAPI convention, the method name just can be Get, Post, Put, Delete.

In your case you have defined `GetOrderStatus` but calling '/api/Order/OrderStatus'. May be that's causing problem.

Comment: Try what Michael suggested.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was that I copied my project to another directory, but "applicationhost.config" file of IIS Express did not change. So when executed from new directory, IIS was trying to execute site from old directory.

Removing entry of site info from applicationhost.config solved this problem for me.